# Vue Change text in input field by useing a button

Tags: button, input, text, vue.js

I have problem with changeing text in my input text field. I would like to let user use "start" button to start my aplication: This should write hours and minutes to the text field and same for the "end" button, when user click on submit. These times and other will be fire on firebase.
Thanks for help and there is my code:

```
<template>
            ...
            <label>Start Time:</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="newAct.startTime" disabled/><br>
            <label>End Time:</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="newAct.endTime" disabled/><br>
            <button @click="submitStart">Start</button>
            <button @click="submitEnd">Stop</button>
            ...
</template>
```

There is my  Code:

```
<script>
...
export default {
...
    submitStart() {
      let t = new Date();
      let time = t.getHours() + ":" + t.getMinutes();
      newAct.StartTime = time;
    },
    submitEnd() {
      let t = new Date();
      let time = t.getHours() + ":" + t.getMinutes();
      newAct.EndTime = time;
    }
  }
...
</script>
```

Comment: if  `newAct` is from your data, you should use `this` : `this.newAct.StartTime = time`  and `this.newAct.EndTime = time`

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I dont understand why it didnt work before.